# Returning Variable holding a string in c and printing it out

Tags: c, string

I have a function like so

```
char *string(FILE *ifp)
{
char string[256];
fscanf(ifp, "%s", string);

return string;
}

int main()
{
.......
printf("%s", string(ifp));
}
```

and it prints NULL, any fixes? Thanks

Comment: you need to allocate memory in order to successfully return your string

Comment: @John This declaration of an array of pointers char *string[256]; does not make a sense.

Comment: `char *string[256];` --> `static char string[256];` or `char *string = malloc(256);`

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL How?

Comment: give me 1mn Im redacting the answer

Comment: are you aware that with fscanf you scan the first word from the file ? meaning that it stops at first space, is it what you want?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL yea thats fine, so i just checked and my code runs fine on repel it but not on code blocks, code blocks returns null but repel is fine although theres a warning on return command saying "address of stack memory associated with local variable 'command' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]"

Comment: you need to malloc or pass a ptr, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a local address, which you should have caught by looking at the warning.

```
In function ‘string’:
warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
 return string;
        ^~~~~~
```

You have two choices:

- Pass a pointer to the char array to your function (string) or
- Malloc the return string (string_from_file)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // for memset

char *string(FILE *ifp, char s[256])
{
    fscanf(ifp, "%255s", s);
}

char *string_from_file(FILE *ifp)
{
    char *s = malloc(256);
    fscanf(ifp, "%255s", s);
    return s;
}


int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    FILE *ifp = fopen(av[1], "r");
    
    // using ptr:
    char s[256];
    memset(s, 0, 256); // fill s with '\0'
    string(ifp, s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    
    // using malloc:
    printf("%s\n", string_from_file(ifp));
}
```

Note that it will only get you the first few words of your program, let me know if it was helpful

NB: I did not rewind the file pointer, so the above example will print first two words.

Comment: Thank You its fixed!

Comment: `fscanf(ifp, "%s", s);` - Wouldn't `fscanf(ifp, "%255s", s);` be better along with checking the return value from `fscanf`

Comment: yes good point, I edited. @John you might accept it as answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Your "char string[]" is a local variable create in your string function, but in C local variable are not stilling availlable after the function was executed (the memory used for this variable is free to be available for an other program);

You can keep the memory for you program with malloc function, but attention never forget to free malloced memory !!

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *get_file_content(FILE *ifp)
{
    char *string = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);

    if (string == NULL)
        return NULL;    //don't continue if the malloc failed
    fscanf(ifp, "%s", string);
     return string;
}

int main(void)
{
    ...
    free(string);    //free memory you malloced
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do not need `sizeof(char)` in `malloc`

Comment: use ```(sizeof(type) * nb_object)``` in your malloc parameter it's just a good usage permit to dismiss mistakes